# Trigger on keyboard event

Tags: javascript, jquery, listjs

I am trying to put together a proof of concept for a touchscreen idea.
I'm not the most skilled with javascript/ jquery so stick with me here as I try to explain myself.

I am using listjs (listjs.com) which I have working fine.
The next step was to build the keyboard.
Now I found this tutorial and followed it and got this working on the same text field (changed from a text-area)

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/creating-a-keyboard-with-css-and-jquery/

If I use my keyboard (physical) to type in the text field the listjs works, but if I use the keyboard I created using tutsplus.com it fills the text box but the lisjs doesn't respond.

I suspect the key is in this line from listjs.js

```
h.addEvent(h.getByClass(options.searchClass, self.listContainer), 'keyup', self.search);
```

I am not really sure what is happening here, way beyond my js skills. I tried (probably naively) changing keyup to change and onchange but that did nothing.

I am testing in Webkit browsers (Safari and Chrome) these are the only two that matter for my project while it's in proof of concept.

I am hoping a js/ jquery guru will come to my rescue and be able to help me out in return for digital flattery.. :)

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I got it working.
I added this to the code for the keyboard.

```
featureList.search(elem.val());
```